# MUI sx and importing a style sheet

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So with the sx prop, i typically style a component like so:

```
<Box sx={{height:'100%'}}></Box>
```

However, I read somewhere yesterday that I could use an import, say a stylesheet, and do it something like this:

```
import style from '';
<Box sx={{style.example}}></Box>
```

I couldn't find anything on this in the documentation, and a quick google search net me zero results for what im looking for. Does anyone have experience doing this?